# How to display exposed sort in views using one drop-down widget?

Tags: 7, theming, views

By default Views 3.0 module for Drupal 7 uses two drop-downs to display exposed sort. First drop-down to select field name, and other one - to select sort direction.

[image: Default Views widget for sorting]

How do i can exposed sort in one drop-down?

[image: New version of exposed widget for sorting]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create small module with following hooks:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 *
 * Alter exposed filter form in views
 */
function MODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['sort_by'])) {
    // Combine sort drop-downs into one.
    $form['sorting'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#id'   => 'sort',
      '#title' => $form['sort_by']['#title'],
    );
    foreach ($form['sort_by']['#options'] as $sort_by_key => $sort_by_title) {
      foreach ($form['sort_order']['#options'] as $sort_order_key => $sort_order_title) {
        $form['sorting']['#options'][$sort_by_key . '|' . $sort_order_key] = $sort_by_title . ' ' . $sort_order_title;
      }
    }

    // Get default value for combined sort.
    $sort_by_keys = array_keys($form['sort_by']['#options']);
    $form['sorting']['#default_value'] = $sort_by_keys[0] . '|' . $form['sort_order']['#default_value'];
  }

  // Explode combined sort field into two values that are appropriate for views.
  if (isset($form_state['input']['sorting'])) {
    $sorting = explode('|', $form_state['input']['sorting']);
    $form_state['input']['sort_by'] = $sorting[0];
    $form_state['input']['sort_order'] = $sorting[1];
  }
}

/**
 * Default preprocess function for all filter forms.
 */
function MODULE_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars) {
  $form = &$vars['form'];

  // Render new created sort field.
  if (isset($form['sorting'])) {
    $form['sorting']['#printed'] = FALSE;
    $vars['sorting'] = drupal_render($form['sorting']);

    // Need to rebuild the submit button.
    $form['submit']['#printed'] = FALSE;
    $vars['button'] = drupal_render_children($form);
  }
}
```

Then you need copy "views/theme/views-exposed-form.tpl.php" file into your theme folder and replace **$sort_by** and **$sort_order** widgets with new **$sorting**

Find:

```
<?php if (!empty($sort_by)): ?>
  <div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-sort-by">
    <?php print $sort_by; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-sort-order">
    <?php print $sort_order; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Replace with:

```
<?php if (!empty($sorting)): ?>
  <div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-sort-by">
    <?php print $sorting; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: How do i change the label for example  "Date de publication ascending" and   "Date de publication descending" to "Recent Prodcuts" and "Older Products"?

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Better exposed filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module for that purpose. It has such option to combine sort field and directions in one select list.

Comment: Thanx for other solution!

Comment: It took me 30 minutes to find that option. On your view, you will find it under BEF settings => Advanced sort options => Combine sort order with sort by. Thanks!!!